# Setstretch for a table

Tags: tables, spacing, lists

I am trying to put a list inside a table, using `p`aragraph mode, but the space between the items is too wide, so I was thinking about using the `setstretch{}` command. Do you know how can I set it in the following example?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=35mm, right=25mm, top=30mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\being{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]          
\caption{Something}
\noindent
\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{|p{3in}<{\raggedright}|p{3in}|} 
\hline      
Preconception Counselling & Pre-pregnancy Care \\             
\hline                
\begin{itemize} \itemsep1pt
\item Pregnancy planning
\item Education regarding the risks and methods to optimize outcome
\item Drugs
\item Referral mechanisms
\end{itemize}
 & 
\begin{itemize} \itemsep1pt
\item Contraception
\item Counselling re risks of diabetes/obesity/glycemic control to:
\item Glycemic control
\begin{itemize}
\item HbA1c: Individualised and realistic targets
\item Self monitoring: 4-7 times daily; pre-meals \textless 6 mmol/l; 1h post meals \textless 8 mmol/l
\item Oral drugs: Stop and initiate insulin if suboptimal control
\item Hypoglycemia: Advice on risks and education of carers in use of glucagon
\end{itemize}
\item Education
\begin{itemize}
\item Dietetic advice regular, but small/moderate carbohydrate portions
\item Weight loss if BMI > 27
\item Regular exercise
\item Smoking and alcohol cessation
\item Sick day rules
\end{itemize}
\item Medications
\begin{itemize}
\item Folic Acid 5 mg daily
\end{itemize}
\item Stop ACEIs, ARBs, statins, diuretics
\begin{itemize}
\item Start methyldopa, labetalol as alternatives
\end{itemize}
\item Screening
\begin{itemize}
\item Rubella immunity
\item Complications (eye, kidney, heart) with referral and treatment as appropriate
\end{itemize}
\item Referral Mechanisms
\begin{itemize}
\item Advice on urgent referral mechanisms if pregnant
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{center}
\label{tab:counselling}         
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And this is the output:
[image]

Comment: `\usepackage{enumitem}` and then `\begin{itemize}[nosep]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the spacing with the `nosep` option from `enumitem`.

I add also some ways to improve your table, for instance how to make it into filling the whole text width without guessing.

Note that the `center` environment should not be used; also it's better if the `\label` sits next to the `\caption`, for easier lookup. I recommend using `siunitx` for units and values, as below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=35mm, right=25mm, top=30mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}

\newenvironment{tabitemize}[1][]
 {\begin{itemize}[nosep,#1]}
 {\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

\caption{Something}\label{tab:counselling}         

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{
  |>{\raggedright}p{.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}|
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}|
}
\hline
Preconception Counselling & Pre-pregnancy Care \\
\hline
\begin{tabitemize}[leftmargin=*]
\item Pregnancy planning
\item Education regarding the risks and methods to optimize outcome
\item Drugs
\item Referral mechanisms
\end{tabitemize}
 &
\begin{tabitemize}[leftmargin=*]
\item Contraception
\item Counselling re risks of diabetes/obesity/glycemic control to:
\item Glycemic control
\begin{tabitemize}
\item HbA1c: Individualised and realistic targets
\item Self monitoring: 4--7 times daily; pre-meals $<\SI{6}{\milli\mol\per\litre}$;
      \SI{1}{h} post meals $<\SI{8}{\milli\mol\per\litre}$
\item Oral drugs: Stop and initiate insulin if suboptimal control
\item Hypoglycemia: Advice on risks and education of carers in use of glucagon
\end{tabitemize}
\item Education
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Dietetic advice regular, but small/moderate carbohydrate portions
\item Weight loss if BMI $>27$
\item Regular exercise
\item Smoking and alcohol cessation
\item Sick day rules
\end{tabitemize}
\item Medications
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Folic Acid \SI{5}{\milli\gram} daily
\end{tabitemize}
\item Stop ACEIs, ARBs, statins, diuretics
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Start methyldopa, labetalol as alternatives
\end{tabitemize}
\item Screening
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Rubella immunity
\item Complications (eye, kidney, heart) with referral and treatment as appropriate
\end{tabitemize}
\item Referral Mechanisms
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Advice on urgent referral mechanisms if pregnant
\end{tabitemize}
\end{tabitemize}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to consider a different way to typeset the table.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=35mm, right=25mm, top=30mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}

\newenvironment{tabitemize}[1][]
 {\begin{itemize}[nosep,#1]}
 {\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

\caption{Something}\label{tab:counselling}

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\textwidth}@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Preconception Counselling}} \\
\midrule
\begin{tabitemize}[leftmargin=*]
\item Pregnancy planning
\item Education regarding the risks and methods to optimize outcome
\item Drugs
\item Referral mechanisms
\end{tabitemize}
\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Pre-pregnancy Care}} \\
\midrule
\begin{tabitemize}[leftmargin=*]
\item Contraception
\item Counselling re risks of diabetes/obesity/glycemic control to:
\item Glycemic control
\begin{tabitemize}
\item HbA1c: Individualised and realistic targets
\item Self monitoring: 4--7 times daily; pre-meals $<\SI{6}{\milli\mol\per\litre}$;
      \SI{1}{h} post meals $<\SI{8}{\milli\mol\per\litre}$
\item Oral drugs: Stop and initiate insulin if suboptimal control
\item Hypoglycemia: Advice on risks and education of carers in use of glucagon
\end{tabitemize}
\item Education
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Dietetic advice regular, but small/moderate carbohydrate portions
\item Weight loss if BMI $>27$
\item Regular exercise
\item Smoking and alcohol cessation
\item Sick day rules
\end{tabitemize}
\item Medications
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Folic Acid \SI{5}{\milli\gram} daily
\end{tabitemize}
\item Stop ACEIs, ARBs, statins, diuretics
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Start methyldopa, labetalol as alternatives
\end{tabitemize}
\item Screening
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Rubella immunity
\item Complications (eye, kidney, heart) with referral and treatment as appropriate
\end{tabitemize}
\item Referral Mechanisms
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Advice on urgent referral mechanisms if pregnant
\end{tabitemize}
\end{tabitemize}
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! However, I forgot to mention that I am using the tabular environment in a document which at the beginning has the command `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}`, so the table goes outside the border of the page. I was thinking therefore to disable the `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}` for the tabular environment, do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Luigi Do `\linespread{1}\selectfont` before `\begin{tabular}`

Comment: Thank you @egreg. Just one more doubt: if the table is too long and I want it to continue on the other page, what command should I use? Should I change `\begin{tabular}` to `\begin{longtable}`?

Comment: @Luigi Yes, that's a possibility, but without the `table` environment and the caption should be part of the table; look at the documentation of `longtable`. In any case, remember that TeX will never break a single table cell across pages.